# Storing multiple rows of integers in a row of integer list/array in sql

Tags: python, mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFzkE.png)
I came across a problem with handling my data load for further calculations.

I get all the data from the database in form of a list of tuples and want to categorize them based on some criteria. 
The list looks like the following:

`a=[(2,1,38),(2,1,44),(2,1,18),...,(77,3,14),(77,3,44),(77,3,19),...]`

The list includes around 1 million tuples as above. As the 1st and the 2nd values of the tuple are repeating themselves and the only value that changes is the 3rd value of the tuple, I was wondering if I could make a new table that has the 1st column as the 1st tuple value, the second column as the 2nd value and the last column as a list of integers that share the same 1st and 2nd values?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can make such a table, but I don't see how that will help you in any way.

Comment: So, I can retrieve the data based on the order of the lists in the DB. Is there a better way to do it? It is important for me to have the order of the data fixed!

Comment: What does your current table look like?

Comment: Please check the image description!
I have 2500 od samples, each of them have 12 time periods and up to 3 route indices. I want to put the travel times that have the same od_id and same route_index in one list, so I can do the rest of my calculation. Also, as each travel time refers to a link, it is very important that the travel times are saved by their order!

Comment: You can GROUP BY the first 2 columns GROUP_CONCAT the 3-rd and order the result as needed. This will give you a result which looks like the table you described.

Comment: The following query is working for me right now, it just does not keep the order of the travel time samples as it should be, would you mind take a look at it and tell me if I can anyhow improve it?

select od_id,route_index,array_to_string(array_agg(travel_time), ',')
from vm.test
group by od_id,route_index,time_period
order by od_id,route_index,time_period

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Rows in MySQL don't have a defined order. Their order depends on the way you retrieve them. You can use ORDER BY inside GROUP CONCAT to order them by some column. If you need them to be in order of insertion, you will need either an auto-increment column or a timestamp.

Comment: Perfect! thanks a lot for your help!